# limit of derivative and differentiable

Tags: limits, derivatives

Let f is differentiable on R. Following statement is true?

If $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)=\alpha$, then $f'(a)=\alpha$ (where $\alpha$ and $a $ are real numbers)

Comment: False. Take f to be the function that is 0 everywhere except at x=1 where it is 1.

Comment: @cauchyproblem That function isn't differentiable.

Comment: Ah ok, so you are assuming the function is differentiable at a.

Answer (score 0):

By mean value theorem, there is $|c_x-a|<|x-a|$ s.t. $$f(x)-f(a)=f'(c_x)(x-a).$$
Since $c_x\underset{x\to a}{\longrightarrow }a$, the claim follow.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we have more than that:

> Let $f$ be a *continuous* function on an interval $I$, $a\in I$. Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $I\smallsetminus \{a\}$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)=\ell\in\mathbf R$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f'(a)=\ell$.